# Reference page in printed asciidoc documentation

Tags: codenameone, asciidoc, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

I want to create a link within an asciidoc PDF for a printed book. The right way to do this is something like:

```
[[LinkUniqueCode]]
Here is the stuff I'm linking to...
Lots of document here...

Now look <<LinkUniqueCode,at the link>>.
```

Normally I would expect this to render as something like this in PDF:

```
Now look at the link (Page 13).
```

But instead I'm getting a link which is useless in a printed PDF...

I've searched a lot for this but the keywords I found are too generic and I only found [this](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#customizing-the-cross-reference-text).

I've tried adding `:xrefstyle: full` but that didn't really help either.

I've seen this both through the fopub backend and the PDF backend. I'm guessing there should be a "print mode" for the PDF generation but I can't really see what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

OK, that was me being stupid. I forgot to include:

```
:doctype: book
```

Which made it all good.

**Edit**:

For full reference here's my entire header:

```
:xrefstyle: full
:listing-caption: Listing
:sectnums:
:pdf-page-size: [8.125in, 10.25in]
:doctype: book
:media: prepress
:icons: font
:source-highlighter: rouge
:toc: macro
:toclevels: 4
:toc-title: Contents
:toc-placement: manual
:tip-caption: :bulb:
:autofit-option:
:hide-uri-scheme:
:uuid: 92CA37B2-EB2B-4B8F-AC7C-XXXXXXXXX
:front-cover-image: image:images/ebook.png[Front Cover,1000,1600]
:lang: en-US
:revdate: 2018-07-22
:doctitle: My Title
:author: Shai Almog
:producer: Codename One Academy
:description: My Description
:keywords: My Keywords,Other Words
:copyright: Shai Almog, all rights reserved
:publication-type: book
```

Then the body of this file is:

```
include::file-names-for-each-chapter.asciidoc[]

[index]
== Index
```

This seemed to work correctly

Comment: Did it allow you to print page number for the text of your links ? (because it seems not possible according to [this](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/2212#issuecomment-381358837) )

Comment: I didn't remember by now but I recall it did work. I recall I ended up using asciidoctor-pdf which was a bit flaky but I was able to get it working. Edited the answer to include the code from the final book. I also wrote this back in the day about the work I had to do in post processing: https://medium.com/sketch-app-sources/using-sketch-and-asciidoc-to-generate-a-professional-tech-book-ef5b5d8dd410

Answer (score 0):

look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312831/asciidoctor-page-number-usable

I took your example and it was not made good.

What other settings like xrefstyle you used?

EDIT: look here:

```
asciidoctor-pdf -v
Asciidoctor PDF 1.5.0.alpha.16 using Asciidoctor **1.5.4** [http://asciidoctor.org]
Runtime Environment (ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux-gnu]) (lc:UTF-8 fs:UTF-8 in:- ex:UTF-8)
```

I think this explains:

On Wed, Aug 9, 2017 at 11:23 PM, Jeremie Bresson [via Asciidoctor :: Discussion] <[hidden email]> wrote:

> The "xrefstyle" feature is really great (new with Asciidoctor **1.5.6.1**, see http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#customizing-the-cross-reference-text )

Comment: I don't understand this answer? How would I reference the page. I was only able to reference the section which wasn't great but I can live with that

Comment: hi, hello, I have the same problem. And I couldnt solve it too. To work with xrefstyle does only work ith asciidoctor 1.5.6.1 AND will not solve the problem to get the pagenumber, but at least some captions and texts.